# "Whet your appetite?" as confirming question

Tags: meaning, idioms

As part of a header on a website, I'd like to say "Have we whet your appetite yet? " or something of similar meaning. Not being a native English speaker, I'm looking for a short/condensed way of saying the above.

I'm thinking of "Whet your appetite?", but I'm not sure this conveys correctly what I'm saying. "Ready for more?" could perhaps be a good alternative.

Comment: "Have we whetted your appetite yet?" is certainly an informal way of saying "Do you like that? Do you want more?" (note the past participle [*whetted*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/whet)). But this type of question falls foul of the [FAQ](http://english.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask).

Comment: @Andrew Leach: It's not a particularly common word to use in the past tense anyway, but I personally have no problem with using *whet* as a past participle. Google Books has 11 *have I whet*, against 47 *have I whetted*, so I might be in the minority, but I'm not alone there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers The OED says that *whet* as a pa. or pa. p. went out of date several centuries ago. The reason you find people using *have whet* today is that they conflate it with *to wet*.  The *which–witch* merger hasn’t helped.

Comment: yup, no problem closing it. I wasn't entirely sure this was the appropriate place to ask. Thanks for the comments

Comment: @tchrist: OED can say what they like - undeniably some people use *whet* as a past participle. You might not consider [this](http://www.wordchamp.com/lingua2/Verb.do?text=to%20whet&languageID=13) as "authoritative" as OED, but are we talking descriptive or prescriptive here?

Comment: @FumbleFingers One need not condone catachresis to document it.

Comment: @tchrist: In matters as marginal as this I don't see much point in calling variants "correct" or "incorrect". There's just "rare" and "even rarer". But personally I don't much like *"I whetted my whistle"*, so it suits me to discover there are apparently **no** instances of that in Google Books.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That because the idiom is *wet my whistle*.   [Witness](https://www.google.com/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=wet+my+whistle&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest#client=opera&rls=en&q=wet%20my%20whistle&oe=utf-8&channel=suggest&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&tbo=u&tbm=bks&source=og&sa=N&tab=wp&psj=1&ei=CfAXUPmpLIin8AHi04C4CA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=93a16cddc0f7ec89&biw=1088&bih=721).

Comment: @Witness: No - it's an idiomatic use of the *verb + noun* in *"to whet one's whistle"*. It just so happens it's mostly used with singular subject *(I, he, John)* in present/future tense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, you can get away with simply saying, "whet your appetite?", if you employ an ellipsis at the beginning like so:

> ... whet your appetite?

Without it, the question sounds odd to me. But it all depends on context. Besides your own alternative, you could also try something like "*Hungry for more?*".